# Encoding issue on setting non UTF-8 body params in NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have trying to emulate HTTP form posting, but faced with non UTF-8 symbols encoding issue.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message":@"Новый день - новые тесты"};
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters: parameters];
```

result of posting this message on site is nil - server received empty message

Then I changed my code:

```
NSString *tmpBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message=%@", message];             
NSData *bodyData = [tmpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:nil];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
```

Result of posting this message on site is: "РќРѕРІС‹Р№ РґРµРЅСЊ - РЅРѕРІС‹Рµ С‚РµСЃС‚С‹"

Then I made another one change:

```
NSData *bodyData = [tmpBody dataUsingEncoding:11];
```

My message sent to server as was needed after this change. But what about symbols from other encoding tables?

The question is how to send post request, to post message in other encodings? How to post cyrillic symbols and symbols like "ěščřžýááíů" together?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using UTF-8 all the time?

Comment: When I use UTF-8, cyrillic string "Новый день - новые тесты" turns  "РќРѕРІС‹Р№ РґРµРЅСЊ - РЅРѕРІС‹Рµ С‚РµСЃС‚С‹" on server after post...
The same effect, when I send string with czech symbols like "ě š č ř"...

Comment: I doubt it.  You aren't looking at the data properly.

Comment: The problem was on the servers side. Sorry